# What is a "timelike half-curve"?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, terminology, causality

I know what a timelike curve is. But what is a time-like *half*-curve, as in the definition of a Malament-Hogarth spacetime (below), which appears [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0104023)?

**Definition**: A spacetime $(M,g)$ is called a *Malament-Hogarth spacetime* iff there is a future-directed, timelike half-curve $\gamma_P : \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow M$ such that $\|\gamma_P\| = \infty$ and there is a point $p \in M$ satisfying $\mathrm{im}(\gamma_P) \subset J^-(p)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the notation implies here, a half-curve is a curve defined from the half-line $\mathbb{R}^+$ (the interval $[0, +\infty)$) to the manifold.